# Need to order output based on date - Sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a simple subquery where I have two tables. First table has the customer id, first name and last name. Second table has the customer id and order date. I want to generate a query that shows the first name, last name and order date.

I have tried the below code and i dont know how the order the output based on date

```
Select 
    Customerid, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName 
From 
    Customer
Where 
   CustomerID IN (select 
                     CustomerID
                  from 
                     orders
                  where 
                     orderdate is not null);
```

The output I show is only the customer id, first name and last name. How do I include the order date in my output.

Comment: why not just do a join that way you won't have a subquery that will hurt performance

Comment: well. you dont have order date on your main query.. so I guess you have to use join instead in order to sort it out by date

Comment: If I wanted to write this as a sub query using IN how would it look?

Answer (score 1):

what did u select = what will display for you, include date in your select statement

```
Select A.Customerid, A.firstname, A.lastname, B.orderdate
From tableA A
Inner join Tableb  B on A.customerid = B.customerid
```

For your modified question(s), try query below

```
Select A.firstname, A.lastname, B.orderdate
From tableA A
Inner join Tableb  B on A.customerid = B.customerid
Order By B.orederdate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;with CustomerProductOrderOrdinal( OrderId, Ordinal )
as
(
    select
        o.OrderId
        , row_number() over ( partition by o.CustomerId, o.ProductId order by o.OrderDate ) Ordinal
    from
        Orders o
    where
        o.OrderDate is not null
        -- filter for product here if so desired
        -- and o.ProductId = <whatever>
)
,FirstCustomerProductOrder( OrderId )
as
(
    select
        OrderId
    from
        CustomerProductOrderOrdinal
    where
        Ordinal = 1
)

select
    c.CustomerId
    , c.FirstName
    , c.LastName
    --, p.ProductId
    , o.OrderDate
From
    Customer c
    inner join Orders o
     on c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
    inner join FirstCustomerProductOrder fcpo
     on o.OrderId = fcpo.OrderId
    -- join with product if you want product info
    --inner join Product p
    -- on o.ProductId = p.ProductId
```

Comment: Thank you and if I wanted to write this as a sub query using IN how would it look?

Comment: @RobertTritt - like a broken query that doesn't produce the result that you're asking for? the `IN()` approach is not going to produce the results you're looking for since an `IN()` doesn't add any new columns to the (outer) result set. If you could describe what's wrong with the above query it might be possible to adjust it to match your requirements. At a guess, there are multiple orders and you only want one order for each client? If so, please specify which order should be selected.

Comment: The query should produce results showing the first and last name with the first date each customer ordered the product.